# Unable to set bottom shadow of UIView in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I want to set the bottom shadow of UIView.I am also setting corner radius.If i set **maskToBounds** to **true** then i am not able to set the shadow of UIView please tell how can i set both corner radius & shadow of UIView.

```
 func addShadwToView(){
    self.viewContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    self.viewContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 15;
    self.viewContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 20)
    self.viewContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    self.viewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.viewContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.viewContainer.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
  }
```

Comment: make sure any other view is not overlapping on it. Otherwise there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Where is `shadowColor`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want both a corner radius and a drop shadow, so don't turn on -masksToBounds, but rather set the corner radius and set the bezier path of the shadow with a rounded rect. Keep the radius of the two the same: 
Try it:

```
func addShadwToView(){
                    var borderLine = CAShapeLayer()
                    borderLine.path =  UIBezierPath(roundedRect: frame2, byRoundingCorners: [.allCorners], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 30, height: 0)).cgPath
                    borderLine.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                    borderLine.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
                    borderLine.shadowOpacity = 0.3
                    borderLine.shadowRadius = 10

                    self.viewContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true;
                    self.viewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                    self.viewContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                    self.viewContainer.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
                    self.viewContainer.layer.addSublayer(borderLine)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...this will solve your problem

```
    func addShadow(){
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customView.frame.width, height: customView.frame.height))
        customView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        customView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 20)
        customView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        customView.layer.shadowRadius = 15
        customView.layer.masksToBounds =  false
        customView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
}
```